# SWI-Prolog stand alone executable

Tags: prolog, exe, swi-prolog

I am trying to create an windows SWI-Prolog executable. I have created the desired executable using this command line argument.

- --goal=main --stand_alone=true -o myprog -c file.pl

but when I try and run the executable it flashes for a second then goes away. I was looking at the documentation that swi-prolog has on this area and it said that I need to have these dlls.

- libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
- libgmp-10.dll
- libswipl.dll
- libwinpthread-1.dll
- zlib1.dll

I have located them in the bin folder, but I am confused at how I get my prolog program to load the dlls. I have read up on the predicate use_foreign_library/1:

`use_foreign_library(FileSpec) :- 506    ensure_shlib, 507    initialization(shlib:load_foreign_library(FileSpec), now)`

but after reading about it I am still confused as to how to use this predicate or if this predicate will help me solve my problem.

Comment: Have you copied the `dll`s to where your executable is?

Comment: Either add the bin folder to your system path or copy the dlls inside the folder where your executable is

Comment: What do you get when you run the Windows equivalent of ldd on `myprog`? You don't need `load_foreign_library/1` unless you have C code you want to include (although it doesn't hurt to add `--foreign=save`). Also try `--undefined=error`. See also https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/swi-generated-executable-is-not-loading-dlls-from-the-local-directory/3678/5

Comment: Yes I do have the dlls in the folder with the executable and I’m still having the same problem.

Comment: Turns out that one of the dlls was actually the wrong dll. When I put the right dlls into the folder everything works fine. Thanks